# env.JavaFX_Home in Maven error

Tags: java, maven

I am using a maven library, and the pom contains such a line:

```
 <javafx.runtime.lib.jar>${env.JAVAFX_HOME}/jfxrt.jar</javafx.runtime.lib.jar>
```

However, in my IntelliJ, the pom shows an error:

```
Can't resolve symbol "env.JAVAFX_HOME"
```

Why is that and how to fix that?

In the same POM.xml, I also see this error:

```
<configFile>${session.executionRootDirectory}/contrib/formatter.xml</configFile>
```

Can't resolve symbol "session.executionRootDirectory"

Answer (score 0):

Whatever environment your `pom.xml` gets processed needs an env variable named `JAVAFX_HOME`

Comment: Where and how to define this JAVAFX_HOME?

Comment: What is your environment  ? Which OS ? your pom.xml gets processed by IDE or from terminal/command prompt ?

Comment: I can compile it fine with "mvn clean compile", but it has this problem when I open it in IntelliJ. I have this problem in both Windows and Linux.

Comment: On Linux /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Comment: For Linux terminal you can set it in `.bash_profile` like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session and for IDe intelliJ refer this https://emmanuelbernard.com/blog/2012/05/09/setting-global-variables-intellij/

Comment: Can't find jfxrt.jar for JDK 1.8.

Comment: It comes with oracle JDK 1.8 , find `jfxrt.jar` the file. and set the ENV variable's value related to it.